Why does "plainnat" not sort the author with natbib in LaTeX>
In the post, it says that the plainnat style in natbib can sort the references by alphabet. But I test it and find it can't. What is the reason?
\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{filecontents*}{egbib.bib}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%egbib.bib
@misc{kristic,
 author = {M. Kristic and I. Kanellakopoulos and P. Kokotovic},
 title = {Nonlinear and adaptive control design},
 journal  = {John wiely and sons, United States of America},
 year = 1995
}
@misc{ref2,
 author = {P. K. Menon and G. D. Sweriduk and S. S. Vaddi},
 title = {Nonlinear discrete time design methods for missile flight control systems},
 journal  = {AIAA, Guidance navigation and control conference },
 year = 2004
}
@article{ref3,
author = {O. Harkegard},
title = {Flight control design using backstepping},
journal = {Licentiate thesis 875 Linkoping university Linkoping Sweden},
year = 2001
}
@article{ref4,
author = {Junguo Lu and Rong Wei and Xiaofan Wang and Zhiquan Wang},
title = {Backstepping Control of discrete time chaotic systems with application to henon system},
journal = {IEEE transaction on ciruits and systems 1},
volume = 48,
pages = {1359--1363},
year = 2001
}
@article{ref5,
author = {Johan Dahlgren},
title = {Robust nonlinear control design for missile using backstepping},
journal = {},
year = 2002
}
@article{ref6,
author = {Diagoro Ito and Jennifer Georgie and John Valasek and Donald T. Ward},
title = {Reentry vehicle flight controls design guidelines Dynamic inversion},
journal = {Report NASA center for aerospace information},
year = 2002
}
@article{ref8,
author = {N.Naveen and S.Geetha and S.Ushakumari},
title = {Backstepping control technique applied to discrete time sytem},
journal = {National Conference on Technological Trends},
year = 2013
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

All physical systems are nonlinear in nature. Nonlinear control design technique like backstepping considers the nonlinearity also during design. The 1991 Bode lecture at IEEE CDC, held by Kokotovic was devoted to backstepping and in 1992 kanellakopoulos presented a mathematical toolkit for design of backstepping control laws. During the following year text books by Kristic \citet{kristic} Freeman , Kokotovic and Sepulchre were published.

The discrete-time feedback control techniques such as feedback linearization, backstepping and state dependent riccati equation methods in \citet{ref2}\citet{ref3} and  missile autopilot design was also considered in \citet{ref2} .The application of discrete time backstepping  to  various systems is given in \citet{ref2}\citet{ref4}.

The backstepping control technique is found to have a lot of advantages compared to feedback linearization and gain scheduling. Backstepping does not require exact model for design \citet{ref3}\citet{ref5}.The backstepping technique can solve tracking and regulator problems. It can also provide dead beat control and exact tracking of any desired trajectory in finite time and exploits the flexibility offered by lower order and scalar systems. Backstepping technique takes advantage of useful nonlinearities which help in making the Lyapunov derivative negative definite \citet{kristic}.The discrete backstepping technique has been applied to roll control and sideslip angle control of a reusable launch vehicle. The system is discretized first and then the controller is developed step by step and has given very good tracking and stabilizing performance.

% Include other packages here, before hyperref.

% If you comment hyperref and then uncomment it, you should delete
% egpaper.aux before re-running latex.  (Or just hit 'q' on the first latex
% run, let it finish, and you should be clear).
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{egbib}

\end{document}



Your bibliography is already in alphabetical order. There is nothing to fix.
The reason it looks odd is because plain is designed for numerical labelling. So it puts
<numerical label> <given name and initials of first author> <family name of first author>

whereas when using author-year citations, you would normally use a bibliography style which put
<family name of first author> <comma> <given name and initials of first author> <year>

to match the author-year labels in the text. This also means that the entries are sorted by the first word in each, because the first word is the last name of the first author.
This is why it is odd and unhelpful to readers, in my opinion, to use a style designed for numerical labels with non-numerical labels. It makes it harder to find bibliography entries using the labels provided in the text.
To fix this, you'd use something like chicago as the bibliography style or you'd use numerical citations. For example,
  \bibliographystyle{chicago}

produces


Why is Diagoro after O. Har...?

I should download harvard?  As I couldn't open style file harvard.bst : \bibstyle{harvard : }

@Y.zeng Try chicago. I probably have the wrong name and chicago seems to work fine. See above.

@Y.zeng But really what you should do if you have any choice over the matter is to use Biblatex and Biber.

[And I don't say that only because I've apparently forgotten how to answer questions about BibTeX/natbib. Rather, I say it because there's a reason I have forgotten how to use BibTeX/natbib.]

Thanks. chicago works well and Biblatex is better than bibtex.

While it's true that plain was designed to produce numeric-style citation call-outs only, it's not true for plainnat. Indeed, if natbib is loaded with the option authoryear, \citet and \citep will produce authoryear-style citation call-outs with the plainnat style. Now, you (and many others...) may find it unfortunate that plainnat places the year block at the very of a formatted bibliographic entry instead of right after the author block.  However, that's separate issue, isn't it?

@Mico Yes. This is another problem. I will choose biblatex.

@Y.zeng - Switching to biblatex will not fix the majority of the issues in your sample document.

@Mico It's not the position of year which strikes me as so problematic, but the first-last name ordering, which makes it much more difficult for a reader to find the entry given a label. While plainnat works in some sense for author-year citations, the style is plain's and that design is clearly done with numerical labels in mind. So, yes, it is designed to work with citations of either style, but 'work' in a technical sense, rather than a content sense.

@Y.zeng Switching to Biblatex won't by itself fix anything. But it is much easier to configure Biblatex because you do not have to speak the language bst style files are written in. And it is also much better at handling modern sources such as online archives etc. And Biber doesn't impose restrictions on things like the ordering in your .bib file.
